# Kali Linux can't boot on VB

Tags: boot, kali-linux, virtualbox

I wanted to install Kali Linux using virtual box. I downloaded Kali.ova file and added it: File->Import Appliance->Import.

I started Kali linux, selected Kali Linux and hit enter.
but it only shows me this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change of TTY?

Comment: .ova ? why not the .iso ?

Comment: I saw on internet how to install Kali. I didn't know that i can install iso @aurelien

Comment: virtualbox for like a charm with iso ;-)

Comment: ok i will try with iso @aurelien

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the .iso file from [Kali iso download](https://www.kali.org/downloads/)

Comment: It still can't boot the same problem